# MySQL query related to GROUP BY and HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to select the number of players in a softball database using GROUP BY and HAVING but am not getting the results I expect. Can someone help me understand what is wrong with this query? I expect it is a simple mistake that I am overlooking.

```
SELECT player_id AS 'players', SUM(sb_stats_HR) FROM 
`softball_stats` AS 'homers' GROUP BY 'players' HAVING 'homers' > 3;
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT 
player_id AS 'players', 
SUM(sb_stats_HR) AS 'homers'
FROM softball_stats  
GROUP BY player_id 
HAVING SUM(sb_stats_HR) > 3;
```

Comment: you are reproducing the query of the OP... or, what is the difference with the OP?

Comment: I didnt get you. Please elaborate.

Comment: thanks, I'll mark it as solved when it's past the 5 minute window. I actually crafted my question incorrectly above. I did have the AS 'homers' in front of the "FROM softball_stats" in my original query, but it still wasn't working. Your solution worked like a charm, though.

Comment: @Aditya always try to include an `ORDER BY player_id ASC` or `ORDER BY NULL` if you want to disable Implicit sorting ... trusting on Implicit sorting with GROUP BY is official deprecated as off version MySQL 5.6 and this "non standard SQL feature" will be removed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks,you are playing with strings.

```
SELECT player_id AS `players`, SUM(sb_stats_HR) 
FROM `softball_stats` AS `homers` 
GROUP BY `player_id ` 
HAVING `softball_stats` > 3;
```

If this doesnt work,edit your post with some sample data.

Comment: You can not use aliases in Group By clause.

Comment: ah, that's something I didn't know. thanks for the information! wish I could award multiple points to everyone for multiple correct answers!

Answer (score 0):

Ticks are used to enclose text. Backticks are used to enclose column or table aliases. So your query is not working because you are trying to enclose column aliases with text enclosing characters. Also, you are trying to filter using `having` on a table alias, not on a column alias, which is incorrect.

Use this:

```
SELECT player_id AS players, SUM(sb_stats_HR)
FROM softball_stats
GROUP BY player_id 
HAVING SUM(sb_stats_HR) > 3;
```

Notice that, if your aliases don't have any special characters or spaces, you don't need to enclose them in backticks.

If you insist in using backticks:

```
SELECT player_id AS `players`, SUM(sb_stats_HR)
FROM softball_stats
GROUP BY player_id 
HAVING SUM(sb_stats_HR) > 3;
```

Notice that, although it is possible to use column aliases in  `having` clause (you can't use them in the `group by` clause), I choose not to use them, for clarity. First understand how it works at the most basic level, and then you can use the tricks.